mask S3 pre-sighed URL for security
I want to mask pre-signed S3 object URL and route it through domain (example.com/S3object). Wondering if this is something can be done through Nginx or some other way.
My concern here is the URL exposes KEY
https://example-images-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/site_1820_plan_1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=#####[…]IYDtY%****%3D&Expires=1721398370
would prefer doing something like example.com/site_1820_plan_1.png so here Nginx access the S3 object through

Amazon S3 buckets with custom domains will work just fine with pre-signed URLs (eg https://example.com/site_1820_plan_1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=#####[…]IYDtY%****%3D&Expires=1721398370). Is that what you were seeking? Or are you worried about displaying the AWSAccessKeyId? That does not particularly impact security -- it's like a Username. The security is controlled by the Secret Key.
